# Cannot return object literal because null or undefined - Flow

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

Mixing the mayBe types with Optional props of an object literal

```
 type Response = {
        data?: string;
    }

 function length(): ?string {
      return undefined;
 }

 function test(): Response {
    const data = length()
    return {
        data
    }
 }

12:         data        ^ Cannot return object literal because null or undefined [1] is incompatible with string [2] in property `data`.
References:
5: function length(): ?string {
                      ^ [1]
2:     data?: string;
              ^ [2]
```

[Test Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7e0C8UDeAoKBUAJgIbAkD8AXFPMAE4CWKA5gNy4C+uuAZgK4oAxsEaooAGwitgACwAUAShoU6TVjnxR6EYP3ooogohF7MIRDtz6CRYw8ATAlNOIlTpNASCEfgxMhIoLCkZBUVcLx09A00CLy9SckjuTiA)

Following the flow documentation for [MayBe types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/) and [Object Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/)
I am not sure why I get the error, is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe types and optional object properties are not quite the same thing in flow, and are not always compatible.

First let's look at your doc link for [Maybe Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/):

> Maybe types accept the provided type as well as `null` or `undefined`. So `?number` would mean `number`, `null`, or `undefined`.

So `?number` is basically `number | null | undefined`.

Now let's look at your Object Types link [from the docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-optional-object-type-properties):

> In addition to their set value type, these optional properties can either be `void` or omitted altogether. However, they cannot be `null`.

So if we do `type Response { data?: string }` then `response.data` is *basically* `string | void`. Note that `void` is a totally separate type from `null`.

So now let's break down your example:

```
type Response = {
  data?: string; // void | string
}

function length(): ?string { // void | string | null
  return undefined;
}

function test(): Response {
  const data = length()
  // at this point, as far as flow knows, `data` can be `void`, `string`, or
  // `null`, and we're trying to set it as the `data` property on our
  // `Response` type which expects a `void` or a `string`, and does not
  // expect a `null`.
  return {
    data
  }
}
```

So basically, `Response.data` is expecting `void | string` and you're trying to set it with a `void | string | null`. A type must change somewhere in order for you to complete the operation successfully. There are multiple possible approaches:

#### [Option one](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7e0C8UDeAoKBUAJgIbAkD8AXFPMAE4CWKA5gNy4C+uuAZgK4oAxsEaooAGwitgACwAUAShoA3JIyJQAPrQbMWOfFHoRg-eiiiCiEXswhEO3PoJFjLwBMCU04iVOiGAJBCAcDEZCRQWFIyCoq4QSZmFoYEQUGk5IncnEA), change `length` return value to be more specific. Probably the simplest:

```
function length(): void | string {
  return undefined;
}
```

We've removed the possibility of `data` being `null`, so no more type error.

#### [Option two](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7e0C8UDeAoKBUAJgIbAkBcUA-PMAE4CWKA5gNy4C+uuAZgK4oAxsEaooAGwitgACwAUASiq0GzFjnxR6EYP3ooogohF7MIRDtz6CRYw8ATAlVOIlTpNASCEfgxMhIoLCkZBUVcLx09A00CLy9SckjuTiA), make `Response.data` a maybe type

If they're both maybe types, the problem goes away. The smallest possible change would be this one:

```
type Response = {
    data?: string | null;
}
```

We've just added the possibility of `Response.data` being `null`. Now it can accept the return type of `length`, types match, no error. But this is a bit confusing, combining the `null` with the optional property. We could just do this instead:

```
type Response = {
    data: ?string,
}
```

#### [Option three](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7e0C8UDeAoKBUAJgIbAkD8AXFPMAE4CWKA5gNy4C+uuAZgK4oAxsEaooAGwitgACwAUAShoU6TVjnxR6EYP3ooogohF7MIRDtz6CRYw8ATAlNOIlTpNASCEfgxMhIoLCkZBUUtAl80fx13NEwcTg5CKEZeKHlSckVNVIIAegKA8jT4KBQkAHcoIIADFH4AWwAjCHo6gBoKpH8G5rb6KAAfKAA3JEYiEYr+CQk6yMI45ASAOmygrE2Uwm4vHT0DbQRV9C4gA), refine the type:

```
function test(): Response {
  const data = length()
  // at this point response.data is `void`
  const response = {};
  if (data) {
    // data is now a `number`, not `number | void | null`
    response.data = data;
  }
  // response.data is now `number | void` (not `null`)

  return response
}
```

The decision of which of these options to use depends almost entirely on the best API for whatever the problem at hand is, and also possibly stylistic choice on how to approach optional vs maybe types in general.

Comment: Such a great answer, thank you for clearing this up for me !

Comment: Hey Lyle does making type Response = { data? = ?string} also is an option to fix this ?

Comment: Yes that would also be an option, but I wouldn't recommend it in almost all situations. You should think about what this means in terms of communication around your API. By using `data?: ?string` you're saying "the `data` property is optional on the object, and its value can either be a `string`, `undefined`, or `null`." Does the user really need that many options? Or is it just confusing?